# Access Provider information in Flutter integration test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-integration-test

I want to access information in one of the Providers used in my app while running integration tests.

I've found some information but doesn't seem to work. I was hoping I could do something like this

```
      User user;

      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UsersProvider()),
          ],
          builder: (ctx, child) {
            return Consumer<UsersProvider>(
              builder: (ctx, usersProvider, _) {
                user = usersProvider.user;
                return app.MyApp();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      );
```

and then after signing in I was hoping to access properties of the `User` model stored in the `Provider` such as; `user.verificationState`.

e.g.

```
      if (user.verificationStatus == VerificationStatus.Verified) {
        // Do something based on verification state
      }
```

but my `user` is always null.

Comment: For easier testing you should migrate from Provider to Riverpod as Provider will be probably deprecated soon, when Riverpod is a continuation.

Comment: This is also true if you try to use a `context.watch(...)`, for some reason which I don't understand the build method will not be called within integration tests but will outside of integration tests when the provider updates. I wonder if this is a bug?